# omp_get_num_threads() always returns 0 (VM Lubuntu C)

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp

```c
int totalMatchCount;
int matchCount = 0;

#pragma omp parallel for private(r, c, matchCount)
for (r = 0; r < x; r++)
{
    for (c = 0; c < y; c++)
    {
        if (approxEqual(rows[r][c], reference, tolerance) == true)
        {
            if (verbose)
            {
                fprintf(stdout, "r = %d, c = %d: %.6f (thread = %d)\n", r, c, rows[r][c], omp_get_thread_num());
            }
            else
            {
                fprintf(stdout, "%.6f\n", rows[r][c]);
            }
            matchCount++;
            totalMatchCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm supposed to iterate through a million-element matrix of numbers and get every number in the matrix that is greater/less than the number reference by less than another number tolerance (i.e: if ref = 5 and tol = 2, any number between 3 and 7 would be verified). If a boolean verbose is set to true (from a flag in the command line), I have to get the current thread number. However, it will only ever return thread = 0. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I'm on Oracle VMWare Lubuntu, if that helps in any way.

I tried compiling and printing out the program (I'm using all of the openmp flags in the gcc -o), but when testing the thread number it will always be 0 (the max number of threads will always be one). The assignment was poorly worded and the sample executable was protected so I couldn't see the output, but I reckon the lecturer wants to see different thread numbers at the very least.

Comment: It deleted all my code formatting, sorry if it's hard to read

Comment: Consider using clang-formatting or even [related online tools](https://zed0.co.uk/clang-format-configurator/) for that if needed. The main problem is certainly that `totalMatchCount` is shared and so there is a *race condition* due to the parallel update of the variable. You certainly need to use a reduction for that. Note the condition will certainly slow down significantly the code. Also note that `totalMatchCount` is not initialized. I think it would be a good idea to share the `approxEqual` function as it may also be not correct for a parallel usage.

Comment: By the way, you need to compile the program with `-fopenmp` so an OpenMP code is generated (not the case by default). Additionally, please do not forget to add optimization flags like `-O3` to benchmark the program (there is no optimization by default).

Comment: Does the VM provide more than one hardware thread? What does `lscpu` say if run there?

Comment: Hi guys, the problem is my VM only has 1 thread per core, one core per socket and only one socket. Will try it on my main OS. Thanks